# Nginx redirect URL with specific query parameter

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting

Nginx, I am trying to permanently redirect the URLs with a `device` GET parameter (http://www.example.org/page?device=desktop) to the relative URL without this parameter (http://www.example.org/page).

I did this, but it doesn't work.

```
location {
    rewrite ^(.*)\?device=desktop $1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Each query parameter is exposed as a [variable prefixed with `$arg_`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) in the configuration file. For example, `device` would become `$arg_device`. Using this you can make the comparison check within your location block, for example:

```
location / {
    if ($arg_device = desktop) {
        return 301 $uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine! Can you also explain me what you did? For each GET parameter I have a $arg_name variable?

Comment: @fede91it Read the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).

Comment: great stuff thanks and very old answer. Wonder how can you just check that argument is only set :D, and ignore the value. I assume just remove `= desktop` part